# How can I create an object with an incremented key in Javascript without losing elements?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an object property that is containing the another object and key is incremented value of the last property of the object.

I am struck in this situation where I am trying to build an object in this format:

```
{
"0":{
 "user":"xyz",
 "group":"abc"
 },
"1":{
 "user":"xyz1",
 "group":"abc1"
 }....

}
```

But, somehow the code overwrites the "1st" element and thus there is always one element less

The system I work on only supports var and nothing like const,let

My code logics:

```
//passed_object(objec passed from function)
var arr = ["user1", "user2", ...];
if (arr.length > 0) {
  // if there are more than one users in the list
  var obj_keys = Object.keys(passed_object);
  for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
    var obj = {};
    if (obj_keys.length === 0) { // create the attributes of the user object in case the user does not in the array of objects
      obj.user = arr[j];
      obj.group = grpDetails.name.toString(); // brought from previous variables

      passed_object[j + obj_keys.length] = obj;
    } else {
      for (var k in passed_object) {
        obj.user = arr[j];
        obj.group = grpDetails.name.toString(); // brought from previous variables
        var mx_val = Math.max(obj_keys.length, parseInt(j + parseInt(obj_keys[Object.keys(obj_keys).length - 1]))); // to get the last variable and create object accordingly
        passed_object[mx_val] = obj;


      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: You're setting `obj.user` and `obj.group` the same way in both `if` and `else`.

Comment: If you want keys that increment 0, 1, 2, why don't you use an array instead of an object?

Comment: `grpDetails.name` is the same every time through the loop. How do you expect to get `abc`, `abc1`, etc. from this?

Comment: Provide the full code to reproduce, and explain more specifically what you want to achieve!